# zsh: How to create a keybinding for history-beginning-search-forward when in vim mode (with oh-my-zsh's vi-mode plugin)?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using the `zsh` shell on my Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm starting to learn how to use `vim` as well.

Having `oh-my-zsh` installed, I actually use the `vi-mode` plugin in order to use vim with zsh.

It works well and it's very handy.

However, before using zsh's vi-mode, I was used to the arrow keys.
There is this widget called `history-beginning-search-forward` in zsh (not sure if this is the correct one though).

When I type the beginning of my command, I could use the arrow keys in order to go back through my history that started with the same command.

This widget doesn't work with vi-mode. When I'm in normal mode, the `j` and `k` keys use the classic history search feature (going to the last command and then back to the previous ones regardless of the command I already typed in).

I would like to know if it's possible to create a custom bindkey for vim's normal mode and to use this widget with my `j` and `k` keys.

And eventually bind the classic search mode to other keys such as `Ctrl+j` and `Ctrl+k` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `.zshrc` file:

```sh
bindkey -M vicmd "j" up-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey -M vicmd "k" down-line-or-beginning-search
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.